# Cannot redirect to expected View ,getting 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Actually I have been working on a Spring MVC lately. I am experiencing odd behavior with the project. 
this is in my dispatcher servlet
`<bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>`

this is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView loginThroughCredentials(@ModelAttribute("EmployeeBean") EmployeeBean bean,HttpServletRequest request){
    System.out.println("in login");
    bean=services.getEmployeeFromLogin(bean);
    if(bean!=null){
        System.out.println("true");
        request.getSession(false).setAttribute("employee", bean);
        return new ModelAndView("homePage");
    }
    return new ModelAndView("../index","error", "Username/Password Not Valid");
}
```

The Issue is , RequestMapping is catching the request with login url pattern.
And executes the method.Method executes properly but I get 404 saying

> HTTP Status 404 - /EmployeeManagementSystem/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp

type Status report

message /EmployeeManagementSystem/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp

description The requested resource is not available.

As you can see I have given homePage or index as a view. but they are never invoked the controller redirects the application to login.jsp view which is not present in my application.

Can you please tell me why this is happening??

Answer (score 0):

I think you can provide little more information, for example what does it print "in login" or "true".  Do you have any Spring Security filter in your application? Are you sure you are using POST in the request?

Comment: It is printing in login and true when the the entry is valid and I am using post method. I have already worked with spring MVC and never encountered such problem. The execution is correct but at the end the ModelAndView takes the pattern and appends .jsp